# Audio driver broken and cant update

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, drivers

FYI my laptop is an Asus U31S, and I'm running windows 8.1 original and official.

So, my problem is that after I've formatted and installed windows 8.1 my audio drivers seem to be having some problems. The audio icon on the taskbar has a red cross on it, and therefore when I click it, it says it can't find the audio and tries to troubleshoot it, unsuccessfully.

When I go to my Device Manager, all I can see that is sound related are:

- High Definition Audio Controller (under the tab System Devices)
- NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM) (Under Sound, video and game controllers)

The High Definition Audio has a yellow exclamation mark, and apparently is not working and when I try to update it, it says it's already the best driver. I have installed all possible windows updates, fyi.

Here's the solutions I've tried:

- Update the High Definition Audio Controller automatically with windows, and I got an "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date."
- Right click the High Def Audio Controller and uninstall it, then restart the PC and let windows install it again, and also click Actions->Scan for hardware changes. It installed it again and went back to yellow exclamation.
- I've followed some youtube guides about uninstalling it, rebooting windows 8 and troubleshooting it, then select F7 on some menu (which was something to make windows not force drivers or something alike), then install the driver locally by going to a realtek driver folder.
- Formatting windows 8.1 again, and again, and again.

I don't know what else to do, and I'm going crazy.

Comment: Have you tried installing the *High Definition Audio Controller* manually from the manufacturer website?

Comment: Yep. Nothing. I've decided I will try installing formatting with Windows 7 and then boosting it to Windows 8, as it was working before. Meaning I had W7 and sound working, boosted it to W8 and it still worked, and only when I formatted to W8 it stopped working.